Why are closed sets necessary for the gluing lemma?
I am currently working through Lee's book series on manifolds, in particular "An Introduction to Topological Manifolds".
I am having a slight problem with the following exercise 3.4:


I think I came up with the following proof:
Uniqueness is obvious. Continuity can be proved by first assuming $V\subseteq Y$ to be open in $Y$. Then $$f^{-1}(V)=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k f^{-1}(V\cap f(A_i)),$$ where each $V\cap A_i$ is open in $f(A_i)$ with respect to the subspace topology.  Now, as each $f_i : A_i \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, I believe (and I think I've got a proof for this), it follows that $f_i : A_i \rightarrow f(A_i)$ is also continuous.
By said continuity each $f^{-1}(V\cap f(A_i))$ is open in X. Now, as unions of open sets are open, f is continuous. $\square$
What irritates me however is that I have nowhere assumed the $A_i$ to be closed. This usually indicates an error in one's proof, but - apart from the little statement that seems quite obvious - I right now don't see anything particularly wrong with it.

Hint: Here's an easy counterexample: Let $X = [0, 1]$, $A_1 = [0, 1/2]$, $A_2 = (1 / 2, 1]$ and let $f_1\colon A_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be constant with value 1 and $f_2\colon A_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be constant with value 2.

"By said continuity each $f^{-1}(V\cap f(A_i))$  is open in $X$" whoah whoah whoah there mister, you've only got that it's open in $A_i$, but that doesn't mean it's open in $X$. There's your problem. Your proof only works if (ironically enough) all the $A_i$ are open.

@MartianInvader Strictly speaking the proof still doesn't work when all $A_i$ are open, although then it is easier to fix.

There are two problems.
The first is that the set $f^{-1}(V \cap f(A_i))$ leads to nowhere because it is not related to $f_i$. Instead it is
$f^{-1}_i (V) = A_i \cap f^{-1}(V)$.
The second is that even if $f$ was continuous the set $f^{-1}(V\cap f(A_i))$ does not need to be open in $X$. This is because $V\cap f(A_i)$ is not necessarily open in $f(X)$.

Thank you, you are of course right. I will go over it again tomorrow. It always seems very obvious in hindsight... :D
